# Prism for Xamarin.Forms: EventAggregator from the platform projects

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

My scenario is like this: 
When I press the back button on my mobile, I want to navigate from the current active viewmodel to another view . 
I would like to rely on the eventAggrigator because it is cool. However, initializing the whole prism thing is kind of challenging, as we do that from "App.cs" 
I tried to think of a way to start the initialization from "MainActivity", but then how do i register the stuff in the container if I do not have a container at that point?

So my question in short , how do i use the eventAggrigator to send a message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to expose a static property off of the Application which simply returns the event aggregator and then use that to access the IEventAggregator in your platform projects

Comment: Thanks , would be nice though if you guys managed to make the initialization starts from the platform (where everything starts).

Comment: Well, essentially it does.  Where it says LoadApplication(new App()); that is when it starts.  So it occurs exactly where everything else does.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Brian.

I have done more or less what you suggested in the following code and it **worked**.

```
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        private IUnityContainer _container;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            var application = new App();
            _container = application.Container;
            LoadApplication(application);
        }

        public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode) {
                case Keycode.Back:
                    var eventAggregator = _container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
                    eventAggregator.GetEvent<BackButtonPressed>().Publish(new object());
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
```